# git pull and resolve conflicts

Tags: git

I am learning git and I have a scenario:

1. My coworker makes changes and pushes the changes to the master.
2. I make changes locally to my master.

So far from my understanding, at this point I can either:

1. Pull the master that my coworker worked on and fix the merge conflicts that I will end up having.
2. Create a back up of my local, clone a new copy of the master, and then merge my changes to the master.

I want to know if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: certainly the first scenario is the preferred one. I'd say the only one.

Comment: do you have any specific problem with it?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new branch every time you want to add a feature. Then when your branch is ready to merge into master, start by pulling the latest version from origin. That way it's cleaner, you don't have to deal with the merge conflicts while doing the pull.

Comment: Better how? What is your current problem and what do you expect for it to be different? Just asking for `better way to do x` is opinion-based and slightly off-topic.

Comment: @user3159253, not any specific problem. Something I came across at work and just wanted to learn if there was any other way to merge changes when two people have worked on it.

Comment: @k0pernikus, you are right. I guess it could be opinion-based. But I mainly for sake of learning wanted to know if there were any other methods or the ones I had put down were industry accepted.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If there are different changes on both the remote and the local branch, instead of just pulling the master by [`git pull`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull), I rather would do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

I even have it in my default config so that it will always will do a rebase if required on `git pull`:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

A rebase avoids a merge commit and keeps your changes on top of the current remote branch.

Yet you still have to resolve any occurring merge conflicts when different people are working on the same branch, which is a bad practice especially because it leads to conflicts.

(Also be aware that in the scope of a rebase, the meaning of `theirs` and `ours` is switched.)

In cases with minor changes, yours are just applied on the top.

You are changing the history, yet only your *local* one, not the remote's.

You *won't* need to `git push --force`. You just `git push` it as you are used to it.

In general, you should be working on feature branches and merge those back to the master branch.

When working on feature branches one can also keep the feature branch close to the `master` by:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git fetch && git rebase origin/master
```

Yet here one would need to `git push --force` the feature-branch, so one should be careful not to use this strategy if more than one person is working on the same feature-branch.

If one wants to use rebase and push forcing, consider using `git push --force-with-lease` over `git push --force` as it prevents accidentally deleting other's commits on the remote.

Comment: I am going to do a test with 'git pull --rebase' as the `rebase` is a new concept to me. Thanks.

Comment: @AsimMahar Rebase is one of the most powerful features of git and I use it often, yet also a great way to shoot yourself in the foot. So be sure to understand the implication of using it.

Comment: @k0pernikus, i just got in the same situation as OP, found your answer, tried to "git pull --rebase" and it says "error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes. Please commit or stash them". What did i do wrong? Thx in advance

Comment: @lucifer63 Please ask follow up question on their own and not in comments. You could link this answer there and also leave a comment here linking to your question. That being said: The help text basically already provides your soluition: Either commit your current unadded and uncomitted (aka unstaged) changes or run stash  `git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash apply`.

Comment: @k0pernikus, i'm just new to stash/rebase features. Thanks for the help and especially for the "unadded and uncomitted (aka unstaged)", it explained a lot!

Comment: @k0pernikus: what does --rebase do ?

Comment: @user1271772 Or more generic: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Answer (score 9):

One (simple*) way to handle this without branching or stashing:

1. stage/commit your changes locally
2. pull remote
3. at this point you'll be notified of any merge conflicts. If git cannot automatically resolve merge conflicts, it will open the two versions in whatever editor you  have set up as your default merge editor. I recommend BeyondCompare.
4. commit your merge, push your merge and commits remote master

Comment: how to add customized commit messages when commiting after the conflicts resolving in Github Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

Best way from my experience is:

1. When working on a new feature, make a new branch cloned from the master. Always keep the branches up to date with the master.
2. After writing and committing your new features to the created branch, you test your app.
3. Then merge master into the working branch, if there are new commits in the master, you may have merge-conflict. After resolving it - test again.
4. If everything is working as supposed to merge your branch to the master.

That's how you can develop many new features and merge only the working ones when you need to deploy. Good luck and check this -> https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git

Answer (score 2):

I believe git sync would be good. Git sync commits your changes, pulls any changes existing in master, then pushes all the changes together to master.

Answer (score 0):

If you're both working on the same file(s), you'll inevitably run into conflicts. You'll just have to learn how to resolve conflicts.

If you want to avoid having to resolve conflicts, then maybe you guys should delegate tasks to each other that involve working on a different files.