# Question on merging with local modifications in Git

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

The following is a very common error message encountered when we try to pull a git repository locally with some existing local changes in the local repository.

`Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting`

I have a question about [stdcall's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877235/stdcall) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745424/) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me).

He has mentioned the following 3 options over there.

[image]

Question:
If I just commit my local changes using the command `git commit -m "Saving my local changes"` Is `git pull` not going to throw the same error that I have mentioned above? I mean I don't need to do a merge (`git merge`) or anything while pushing to GitLab?

In a normal workflow when I don't see any error, I follow the steps below to commit and push my changes:

1. `git add`
2. `git commit -m "My message"`
3. `git push`

Since I am getting above error, are the following steps correct:

1. `git commit -m "Saving my local changes'`
2. `git pull // This will pull whatever is on the branch including my local changes`
3. `git push //This will push my local changes to git`

I have used `git stash` in the past and it has resulted in my local changes getting wiped out so I am scared of using it. I didn't do git stash pop though and probably that's the reason it behaved like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is throwing that error because the working directory is not clean for it to do a `merge`. Since, and I am oversimplifying it here, `git pull` is basically a fetch + merge, git needs a way to merge files. It can't merge if there are changes that are not saved/discarded/stashed.

**This does not save you from conflicts** - getting remote changes **might** cause local conflicts - remote changes touch upon files that you have touched thus causing conflicts. Thus, standard conflict resolution is needed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025587/git-pull-and-resolve-conflicts) for more details.

---

> I don't merge when I push

You don't but not every push you do is successful. Sometimes, there are changes in the remote you don't have. Then git will tell you **"Hey! There are things in the remote that you don't have and I can't override just like that. Pull them so that you can resolve whatever you need to resolve so that you can then push cleanly"**. See, now git tells you to pull - hence merge - so that you can push (of course unless you `push --force`...)

Comment: Thanks. So what I have described is not a recommended approach you would say?

Comment: It's perfectly valid. I just linked to an another answer since there it's discussed the possibility of `git pull --rebase`. There is nothing wrong with committing and pulling.

Comment: Ok, that worked. However, in one of the file - properties.js, after git pull , my IDE was asking whether I should accept incoming merge or not with some <<<<< symbols. So I clicked on it and it showed the exact changes that I was pulling from the git.

Comment: This is expected for a so called [git conflict](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts). Your IDE probably tries to make your life easier to resolve such conflicts by just clicking on what you want to save and what to discard.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` fetches the latest changes and performs a merge via a single command. From its [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

So what you describe will work. First, your `git commit` will create a local commit of your changes. Then, `git pull` will get the new updates from the remote and merge it with your local changes, creating a new merge commit if necessary. Then `git push` will push all of it back to the remote.